# How to eliminate unwanted small regions in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I applied a segmentation algorithm to a MRI spine image and then connected component analysis on the segmented image and obtained the following image.

This image consists of unwanted regions.I just need the vertical spine and more specifically the intervertebral disc. Can you suggest any method to extract it .Morphological operations will not help. I had tried it

- [image: img1]
- [image: img2]

Some code:

```
Img= imread('sub.png');
figure,imshow(Img);
Img=rgb2gray(Img);
Img = adapthisteq(Img);
K1=imadjust(Img);
figure, imshow(Img), title('After Adjustment Image')
hy = fspecial('sobel');
hx = hy';
Iy = imfilter(double(Img), hy, 'replicate');
Ix = imfilter(double(Img), hx, 'replicate');
gradmag = sqrt(Ix.^2 + Iy.^2);
figure, imshow(gradmag,[]), title('gradmag')
%threshold = graythresh(im);
originalImage = im2bw(Img,.18);
figure, imshow(originalImage), title('After thresholding')
originalImage = bwareaopen(originalImage,150);
figure, imshow(originalImage), title('After bwarea')
k=2;
tic
[mask1,mu1,v,p]=EMSeg(ima,k);
for i=1:k
    figure
    im2bw(mask1==i);
end
toc
im=mask1;
hy = fspecial('sobel');
hx = hy';
Iy = imfilter(double(im), hy, 'replicate');
Ix = imfilter(double(im), hx, 'replicate');
gradmag = sqrt(Ix.^2 + Iy.^2);
figure, imshow(gradmag,[]), title('gradmag')

se = strel('disk', 1); %# structuring element
closeBW = imclose(gradmag,se);
CC = bwconncomp(closeBW);
L = labelmatrix(CC);
[labeled,numObjects]= bwlabel(im);
numObjects 
figure, imshow(label2rgb(L));
originalImage=labeled;
se = strel('disk', 1); %# structuring element
originalImage = imclose(originalImage,se);
figure, imshow(originalImage);
stats = regionprops(labeled, 'Area')
%idx = find([stats.Area]>1000 & [stats.Area]<300);
 labeled=labeled(labeled<50)
```

Comment: Show us some code of what youve tried!

Comment: And the original image and the result you'd like to have, because I don't know which bit the intervertebral disc is.

Comment: edited with code and original image

Comment: Why not just crop and mask your image?

Comment: looks like you are using black as contour color  which is present in the unwanted regions also and indistinquishable from the spine regions. so try to search the light gray from spine discs ... form a polygon of area enclosing all found and use that as mask ... +/- some border or segmentate the disc based on area of segment ...

Comment: @user1234 1. take the gray color from it manually at first from that image of yours it looked different then the rest. 2. create bit image  where 0 is any color 1 is color near this gray (+/- some treshold difference) 3. segmentate the image 4. discard areas with too small or too big area (also some treshold)  5 you can try to discard non plate shapes that are not rectangular like with some aspect but you need to take rotation into account. if it works as expected the try to find the position of gray on histogram to make this automatic

Comment: Why did you remove images? Had add them back image has 2 lines the `![text][number]` is the image in text and the link at the end if you delete any of these the image is gone from output

Comment: @user1234 OK again then: 1. take the distinct color (try around #303030 hex or  #474747 hex they seem to be distinct an repetitive inside spine) then create new image of the same size (blank color = 0) process original image pixel by pixel and if found pixel color close to the selected distinct color set the color in the new image to white (#FFFFFF or whatever else then zero)  to the same position as tested pixel in original image. This will be your mask. Now do a flood fill to each nonzero pixel in new image and count the filled area in pixels. If found area too small or too big blank it.

Comment: targetColor = [47 47 47];
[filename, folder] = uigetfile();
img = imread(fullfile(folder,filename));

% look for match
figure,imshow(img),title('Original image');
for i = 1:3
    mask(:,:,i) = img(:,:,i)==targetColor(i);
end

% build boolean mask
mask = mask(:,:,1)&mask(:,:,2)&mask(:,:,3);
figure,imshow(mask),title('Mask');

Comment: @Spektre i tried this code but i didnt got the answer

Comment: the [47,47,47] is in Hex I hope .... if in Dec then it is different shade of gray color coding #RRGGBB is alway in hex ...

Comment: yes it is hex.wat's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use 2D correlation. Assuming the intervertebral discs are the horizontally-oriented elliptical shapes (in the two-colour image) you could try defining an example shape that looks roughly like what you want to find and then performing 2D correlation over the whole field. You'll get an image with, hopefully, brighter points corresponding to the centres of the discs, which you can use for the starting points for a more complex process. You may have to do this repeatedly, using a family of kernels.

Also, although morphological operations didn't solve the problem directly there may still be a role for them. For instance if you define a structuring element that looks somewhat like your target shape you could erode the image with that to try and reduce the linear parts of the image (e.g. the spine), then perform your correlation on that.

Alternatively you could try using morphops to close the discs (heavy opening and closing) with the aim of smoothing off all the edges and filling all the holes. Then you could extract the skeleton, prune short branches and walk the resulting tree looking at the connectedness of each node: hopefully if you've transformed each disk into a solid ellipse perched between two rails you might be able to detect them based on that.

Comment: You need a 'kernel', or a small 'ideal' image to search for, something that looks vaguely like all your discs but not too specific. You will probably have to construct one manually by cutting the discs out of your training set and averaging, or something like this. But this isn't a recipe for successfully completing your problem, these are just ideas to get you started. If they're are new to you then I would highly recommend starting with some textbooks - szeliski.org/book is a great place to start. Hastie and Tibshirani if you want the maths.